# WSO2 5.9 userinfo endpoint for OIDC

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I try to use `https://myidentity/oauth2/userinfo` for extract information about the logged user, but only returns one field

```js
{
    "sub": "username"
}
```

I have complete mapped fields from `http://wso2.org/claims/photo` to `http://wso2.org/claims/oidc/photo`

[image]

What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Since the claims that you are requesting are on the local claim dialect you can use the local claim dialect for requesting claims. Please refer to the official documentation for more information[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wda2O.png)

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wda2O.png).https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/configuring-claims-for-a-service-provider/